# SQL query where id=… or id=… or id=… etc

Tags: sql, postgresql

I haven't had much experience with postgresql (none) and I am wondering/hoping that there is a better way for me to do this query.

```
SELECT * FROM member_copy WHERE id = 17579 OR id = 17580 OR id = 17582 ect.
```

There are about 800 where clauses in total so this will take a while and I need to run it on a fairly regular basis.

Comment: If there are really 800 where clauses I think you should work on your application

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The way to write that query is:

```
SELECT * FROM member_copy WHERE id IN (17579, 17580, 17582);
```

However, the real question is, where did that list of `id`s come from?  If the list of `id`s is the result of another database query, then you should be doing either a subselect or a join instead.

Comment: Worked perfectly. It was not from a database query, somebody actually went through and picked out every number. I do not envy them.

Answer (score 8):

A test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE` will show you that the form with `id IN (...)` in the [answer of @200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/36816/9501) is transformed internally into:

```
SELECT * FROM member_copy WHERE id = ANY ('{17579, 17580, 17582}');
```

.. which therefore performs slightly faster to begin with (no conversion needed).

Also, the form in your question will effectively perform very similar.

With big lists, [unnesting an array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE), followed by a `JOIN` will generally be faster:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM   unnest('{17579, 17580, 17582}'::int[]) id
JOIN   member_copy m USING (id);
```

Since the list is `is the result of another database query`, it will be fastest to combine both in *one* query with a `JOIN`.

More detailed explanation:

- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31192557/939860)
- [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/91247/3684)

Answer (score 0):

For a single id the following query worked for me:

```
SELECT * FROM member_copy WHERE id IN ('17579');
```

Comment: Could you explain how this answers the OP?